# ¿Que está mal en este codigo para AMP Wordpress?

Tags: amp

Tengo el siguiente código que inserta anuncios en AMP. El primer anuncio funciona correctamente, y el segundo, que se debe mostrar al final del contenido, no se visualiza.

Si elimino la parte que inserta el primer anuncio, entonces el segundo sí funciona:

¿Qué hace falta para que funcione?

```html
 <!--Post Content here-->
 <div class="amp-wp-content the_content">
  <?php global $redux_builder_amp;
   
   do_action('ampforwp_before_post_content',$this); //Post before Content here 
   $amp_custom_content_enable = get_post_meta( $this->get( 'post_id' ) , 'ampforwp_custom_content_editor_checkbox', true);
   // Normal Front Page Content
   if ( ! $amp_custom_content_enable ) {
    $ampforwp_the_content = $this->get( 'post_amp_content' ); // amphtml content; no kses
   } else {
    // Custom/Alternative AMP content added through post meta
    $ampforwp_the_content = $this->get( 'ampforwp_amp_content' );
   }
   //Filter to modify the Content
   $ampforwp_the_content = apply_filters('ampforwp_modify_the_content', $ampforwp_the_content);
   if($redux_builder_amp['amp-pagination']) {
    $ampforwp_new_content = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $ampforwp_the_content);
       $queried_var = get_query_var('page');
       if ( $queried_var > 1 ) {
         $queried_var = $queried_var -1   ;
       }
       else{
         $queried_var = 0;
       }
       echo $ampforwp_new_content[$queried_var];
    } else{
     

$ampforwp_the_content = explode("</p>", $ampforwp_the_content); //Every Paragraph tag into Array
$p_number = 1; // Giving default value for paragraph
/* Start Looping */
foreach($ampforwp_the_content as $ampforwp_content){
  
echo $ampforwp_content;
/* Ad after 4th paragraph */
if($p_number == '1'){
 echo'444<amp-ad class="amp-ad-1" type="adsense" media="(max-width: 649px)"  width=300 height=100 layout="responsive" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"></amp-ad>';
}
  
echo '</p>'; $p_number++; // closing and increment every P tag. 
} 
    }//#1015 pegazee
do_action('ampforwp_after_post_content',$this) ; //Post After Content here 

    $totalParagraphs = substr_count($ampforwp_the_content, '</p>');
  if ($totalParagraphs > 4) {
   echo '<div style="margin-top:25px" class="amp-ad-wrapper amp_ad_1 ampforwp-incontent-ampforwp-incontent-ad ampforwp-incontent-ad2"><amp-ad class="ampforwp-incontent-ad ampforwp-incontent-ad2" type="adsense" width="300" height="250" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="925752"></amp-ad></div>';
  }
?>

 </div>
```

Gracias.

El que no funciona es:

```html
    $totalParagraphs = substr_count($ampforwp_the_content, '</p>');
  if ($totalParagraphs > 4) {
   echo '<div style="margin-top:25px" class="amp-ad-wrapper amp_ad_1 ampforwp-incontent-ampforwp-incontent-ad ampforwp-incontent-ad2"><amp-ad class="ampforwp-incontent-ad ampforwp-incontent-ad2" type="adsense" width="300" height="250" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="925752"></amp-ad></div>';
  }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackvorflow. Evita usar fragmentos para código que no se puede probar, no aporta nada (si presionas `Ejecutar` comprenderás lo que digo), más bien dificulta el análisis del contenido. En esos casos es mejor poner el código identado y nada más. En cuanto a la pregunta, ¿probaste que esta condición se cumple: `if ($totalParagraphs > 4) {`?  si no es mayor que `4` no se mostrará el contenido.

Comment: Sí, claro lo he verificado. De hecho si elimino la parte que ejecuta el primer anuncio, el segundo se muestra.

Comment: ¿Cuál es esa 1ª parte de la que hablas?

Comment: $ampforwp_the_content = explode("</p>", $ampforwp_the_content); //Every Paragraph tag into Array
$p_number = 1; // Giving default value for paragraph
/* Start Looping */
foreach($ampforwp_the_content as $ampforwp_content){
  
echo $ampforwp_content;
/* Ad after 4th paragraph */
if($p_number == '1'){
 echo' ffff<amp-ad class="amp-ad-1" type="adsense" media="(max-width: 649px)"  width=300 height=100 layout="responsive" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"></amp-ad>';
}
  
echo '</p>'; $p_number++; 
}

Comment: No sabría qué decirte, aparte de que revises la lógica (comparar que cada `if` toma el camino correcto. Y asegurarte que efectivamente es posible mostrar más de un contenido `amp` ... dado que es algo que no utilizo no puedo decirte nada más, pero puedes probar a poner dos contenidos seguidos de una manera simple (sin condicionales ni nada) para ver si se muestran, si no se muestran entonces puede que no permita poner más de uno o que debas cambiar algo en la configuración de esa herramienta.